# How to manage multiple rsocket clients in SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, rsocket

I need some some help creating a mechanism where I can send requests to multiple clients from Spring server and fetch response. I went through few examples and [rsocket reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/rsocket.html#rsocket-annot-responders-client), but I couldn't understand how to work with multiple clients. I think, I need to create and store RSocketRequester for each client(in a Map). I may be wrong. Kindly help.

Comment: Do you mean a load-balancing case or do you have multiple different endpoints?

Comment: multiple different endpoints. My client are web users(rsocket js). Requests from spring-server will be made periodically to these web users.

Comment: you may find the following example useful https://github.com/rsocket/bomberman-workshop/blob/master/game-service/src/main/java/xyz/bomberman/player/PlayersController.java